# Portable way to read a file in C++ and handle possible errors

Tags: c++, boost, file-io

I want to do a simple thing: read the first line from a file, and do a proper error reporting in case there is no such file, no permission to read the file and so on.

I considered the following options:

- `std::ifstream`. Unfortunately, there is no portable way to report system errors. Some other answers suggest checking `errno` after reading failed, but the standard does not guarantee that `errno` is set by any functions in iostreams library.
- C style `fopen`/`fread`/`fclose`. This works, but is not as convenient as iostreams with `std::getline`. I'm looking for C++ solution.

Is there any way to accomplish this using C++14 and boost?

Comment: Is it an option to implement a stream or stream-like class using the C functions? Allthough yes id agree, io streams for files, sockets, etc. is not great.

Comment: Of course it is possible to implement it, but I hope that in modern C++ there is out out-of-the-box solution for such a simple and common task.

Comment: Boost has stuff to make custom streams easier, but I dont recall one out of the box. Many larger frameworks have file etc. classes, and there are many libraries. But nothing much in the standard library.

Comment: Yes, there's a way to "accomplish this using C++14". Implement your own subclass of `std::streambuf`, then use it to construct a `std::istream`. You get an ordinary stream, and your implementation can use OS calls to open/read the file, and report the actual OS errors.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik This sounds horrible.

Comment: Well, if one's goal is to capture the underlying OS errors, and still have an ordinary `std::istream`, this is the only way to do it. Unfortunately, C++ does not have a reputation for having a lot of magic buttons that one only needs to push in order to get the results they're looking for. Many things require a lot of work to implement correctly, and properly.

Comment: Have you tried to check filesystem::exists and filesystem::file_status::permissions before opening the file?

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky This is totally inappropriate because it introduces the TOCTTOU problem.

Comment: @OlegAndriyanov I believe the more widely used jargon is "race condition" (I had to google TOCTTOU to get it)

Comment: "the standard does not guarantee that errno is set by any functions in iostreams library". The standard says just about nothing about errno. When ENOENT is set? The standard is silent. EACCESS? Nothing. EAGAIN? Nada. Will `perror` print a user-friendly error message or something alongthe lines of "an error occurred, reboot now"? Who knows? If you want any guarantees, you need a guarantee provider other than the C++ standard.

Comment: About "C does it better". The C standard mandates exactly three errno-related macros: EDOM, EILSEQ and ERANGE, and no guarantees about any I/O functions setting errno to anything in particular.

Comment: @n.m. you could say "C does it better" because it abstract 0% over POSIX. This _also_ means, no loss of fidelity (like the C++ libs), aside from the minor quip that there's no abstraction - at all. So it's easier to do the wrong thing in C, but it's more possible to do the right thing well. Plot twist: C++ afords 100% the same. **TL;DR** It's just an expectation mismatch.

Comment: @n.m. Yes it does better. At least C functions do set `errno`, and `perror` documentation in C11 standard says that it "maps the **error number** in the integer expression errno to an **error message**". See, at least it has error numbers. Of course they are implementation defined, but in fact we get "No such file or directory" with `perror` while libstdc++ leaves us with with something like "basic_ios::clear: iostream error" in exception object.

Comment: `perror` prints "No such file or directory" in **your** implementation of C. The C standard doesn't guarantee you that. `perror` prints exactly the same "No such file or directory" in my implementation of C++ when using iostreams. Tell me again why exactly C is better?

Comment: Because C library functions are guaranteed to set `errno` to the (implementation defined) value. C++ iostreams are not required to set `errno`. You get the same output just because your iostreams backend is implemented using system calls from libc, but it is surely not required to be implemented that way. So checking `errno` with `stdio` functions in C is portable, but it is not portable in C++ with `fstream`. That's why I think error handling is better in C.

Comment: C library functions are not guaranteed to set `errno` to values you will like or find useful. An implementation-defined value is all that is guaranteed in most cases. For example they all may set errno to EUNKNOWNERROR. If you happen to be on a POSIX system yoiu get more guarantees. They are of course non-portable to non-POSIX systems but this isn't even important. (to be continued)

Comment: Restricting our attention to POSIX systems, what do you prefer: spend your time implementing a custom IO system with guaranteed error reporting, or producing useful, working, **portable in practice** software that relies on non-standards-guaranteed errno being set by implementation the right way? I personally trust implementations to be non-evil and do the right thing, in this and other cases, but YMMV.

Comment: I also trust implementations to be non-evil, and in that sense C standard (even without POSIX) is enough to do a portable (in practice **and theory**) error reporting, while C++ is not.

Comment: I have actually read the C standard and I don't find it supporting anything remotely like portable reporting of I/O errors. The standard specifies exactly three I/O functions that are guaranteed to set errno (to an implementation-defined value): fgetpos, fsetpos and ftell. I don't see how this can possibly be taken as a basis for portable error reporting. If you find something else in your copy of the standard, please share.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152683/discussion-between-oleg-andriyanov-and-n-m).

Answer (score 17):

Disclaimer: I am the author of AFIO. But exactly what you are looking for is https://ned14.github.io/afio/ which is the v2 library incorporating the feedback from its Boost peer review in August 2015. [See the list of features here](https://ned14.github.io/afio/).

I will of course caveat that this is an alpha quality library, and you should not use it in production code. However, quite a few people already are doing so.

How to use AFIO to solve the OP's problem:

Note that AFIO is a very low level library, hence you have to type a lot more code to achieve the same as iostreams, on the other hand you get no memory allocation, no exception throwing, no unpredictable latency spikes:

```
  // Try to read first line from file at path, returning no string if file does not exist,
  // throwing exception for any other error
  optional<std::string> read_first_line(filesystem::path path)
  {
    using namespace AFIO_V2_NAMESPACE;
    // The result<T> is from WG21 P0762, it looks quite like an `expected<T, std::error_code>` object
    // See Outcome v2 at https://ned14.github.io/outcome/ and https://lists.boost.org/boost-announce/2017/06/0510.php

    // Open for reading the file at path using a null handle as the base
    result<file_handle> _fh = file({}, path);
    // If fh represents failure ...
    if(!_fh)
    {
      // Fetch the error code
      std::error_code ec = _fh.error();
      // Did we fail due to file not found?
      // It is *very* important to note that ec contains the *original* error code which could
      // be POSIX, or Win32 or NT kernel error code domains. However we can always compare,
      // via 100% C++ 11 STL, any error code to a generic error *condition* for equivalence
      // So this comparison will work as expected irrespective of original error code.
      if(ec == std::errc::no_such_file_or_directory)
      {
        // Return empty optional
        return {};
      }
      std::cerr << "Opening file " << path << " failed with " << ec.message() << std::endl;
    }
    // If errored, result<T>.value() throws an error code failure as if `throw std::system_error(fh.error());`
    // Otherwise unpack the value containing the valid file_handle
    file_handle fh(std::move(_fh.value()));
    // Configure the scatter buffers for the read, ideally aligned to a page boundary for DMA
    alignas(4096) char buffer[4096];
    // There is actually a faster to type shortcut for this, but I thought best to spell it out
    file_handle::buffer_type reqs[] = {{buffer, sizeof(buffer)}};
    // Do a blocking read from offset 0 possibly filling the scatter buffers passed in
    file_handle::io_result<file_handle::buffers_type> _buffers_read = read(fh, {reqs, 0});
    if(!_buffers_read)
    {
      std::error_code ec = _fh.error();
      std::cerr << "Reading the file " << path << " failed with " << ec.message() << std::endl;
    }
    // Same as before, either throw any error or unpack the value returned
    file_handle::buffers_type buffers_read(_buffers_read.value());
    // Note that buffers returned by AFIO read() may be completely different to buffers submitted
    // This lets us skip unnecessary memory copying

    // Make a string view of the first buffer returned
    string_view v(buffers_read[0].data, buffers_read[0].len);
    // Sub view that view with the first line
    string_view line(v.substr(0, v.find_first_of('\n')));
    // Return a string copying the first line from the file, or all 4096 bytes read if no newline found.
    return std::string(line);
  }
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of code which reads a line from a file using AFIO? This looks like what I need but I haven't found any code examples.

Comment: @OlegAndriyanov That's a good idea. Back in a few mins with something.

Comment: @OlegAndriyanov Example of use code added. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: That looks like pretty nice wrapper around OS calls. Are there any plans for inclusion of AFIO in boost? Also IMO it would be nice to have an implementation of `std::streambuf` in AFIO (as @SamVarshavchik suggested) to reuse all the power of formatting IO operations of iostreams but with portable error handling. Or is it beyond the scope of the library?

Comment: @OlegAndriyanov I hope to return AFIO for its second Boost peer review in 2019. I'm blocked on the Coroutines TS, Ranges TS, Expected and Span proposals and a few other bits coming in C++ 20. No need to add streambuf support, AFIO uses the Ranges TS already. So speak i/o with Ranges, all works very nicely. Eric did a blog post on this at http://ericniebler.com/2017/08/17/ranges-coroutines-and-react-early-musings-on-the-future-of-async-in-c/, he used libuv instead of AFIO as it's wider known. But AFIO is *far* more efficient than libuv, and WG21 is currently smiling on AFIO for iostreams v2

Comment: I would also add that it's straightforward to implement `streambuf` with AFIO, donations of a high quality implementation with comprehensive test suite are welcome. My main reason for not doing so myself is "other fish to fry first", and as I mentioned, AFIO was designed for the Ranges TS which is the beginnings of the future iostreams reboot.

Answer (score 1):

People on boost-users mailing list pointed out that the [boost.beast](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/beast/doc/html/index.html) library has OS-independent API for basic file IO **including proper error handling**. There are three implementations of the [file concept](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/concepts/File.html) out-of-the-box: POSIX, stdio and win32. The implementations support RAII (automatic closing on destruction) and move semantics. The POSIX file model automatically handles `EINTR` error. Basically this is sufficient and convenient to portably read a file chunk by chunk and, for example, explicitly handle the situation of absence of a file:

```cpp
using namespace boost::beast;
using namespace boost::system;

file f;
error_code ec;
f.open("/path/to/file", file_mode::read, ec);
if(ec == errc::no_such_file_or_directory) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do could be to wrap [Boost WinAPI](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/winapi/doc/html/index.html) and or POSIX APIs.

The "naive" C++ standard library thing (with bells and wistles) doesn't get you too far:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b49c986f3aa57a29)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

template <typename Out>
Out read_file(std::string const& path, Out out) {
    std::ifstream s;
    s.exceptions(std::ios::badbit | std::ios::eofbit | std::ios::failbit);
    s.open(path, std::ios::binary);

    return out = std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{s}, {}, out);
}

void test(std::string const& spec) try {
    std::vector<char> data;
    read_file(spec, back_inserter(data));

    std::cout << spec << ": " << data.size() << " bytes read\n";
} catch(std::ios_base::failure const& f) {
    std::cout << spec << ": " << f.what() << " code " << f.code() << " (" << f.code().message() << ")\n";
} catch(std::exception const& e) {
    std::cout << spec << ": " << e.what() << "\n";
};

int main() {

    test("main.cpp");
    test("nonexistent.cpp");

}
```

Prints...:

```
main.cpp: 823 bytes read
nonexistent.cpp: basic_ios::clear: iostream error code iostream:1 (iostream error)
```

> 1. *Of course you can add more diagnostics perusing `<filesystem>` but 
>      that's susceptible to races, as mentioned (depending on your application, these can even open up security vulnerabilities, so just say "No").*
> 2. Using `boost::filesystem::ifstream` doesn't change the exceptions raised
> 3. Worse still, using Boost IOstream fails to raise any errors:
>
>    ```
>    template <typename Out>
>    Out read_file(std::string const& path, Out out) {
>        namespace io = boost::iostreams;
>        io::stream<io::file_source> s;
>        s.exceptions(std::ios::badbit | std::ios::eofbit | std::ios::failbit);
>        s.open(path, std::ios::binary);
>
>        return out = std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{s}, {}, out);
>    }
>    ```
>
>    Happily prints:
>
>    ```
>    main.cpp: 956 bytes read
>    nonexistent.cpp: 0 bytes read
>    ```
>
>    **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11840739d5d5c176)</kbd>**

Comment: What are these examples for? To demonstrate that they don't do what I want to do? I don't think manual API wrapping is a good idea since this task is easily solved in any modern language in a few lines. Even C does it better than C++.

Comment: Information is everything. If you knew, you could have shown it in your question. Also, [I share the rant](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/38808019#38808019), but that's not a useful answer. (It's even a questionable attitude).

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: boost wraps `ifstream` and `ofstream` and handles correct pathing so you have unicode on both platforms

Comment: @Mgetz That's cool, but unicode paths have nothing to do with system errors like no such file, etc.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, should be a comment.

Comment: Honestly, I think this answer presents research that could have been part of the question. Because it was not, I present it here as a body of work to avoid others having to try the same things. It's not like these parts are well documented (which is why the question is so relevant).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <system_error>

using namespace std;

int
main()
{
    ifstream f("testfile.txt");
    if (!f.good()) {
        error_code e(errno, system_category());
        cerr << e.message();
        //...
    }
    // ...
}
```

ISO C++ Standard:

> The contents of the header
>   "cerrno"
>   are the same as the POSIX header
>   "errno.h"
>   , except that
>   errno
>   shall
>   be defined as a macro. [
>   Note:
>   The intent is to remain in close alignment with the POSIX standard.
>   — end
>   note
>   ] A separate
>   errno
>   value shall be provided for each thread.

Comment: Checking `errno` is not portable as I've said.

Comment: If you believe `fopen` sets `errno` but `ifstream::open` does not, use `fopen`. But note that ISO C doesn't say anything about `errno` in the `fopen` section (compare this against `fgetpos`, `fsetpos`, `ftell`,...). Note also that ISO C knows exactly 3 error codes for `errno` while ISO C++ mentions all POSIX error codes and maps those to `errc`.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that iostreams makes no guarantees that errno will be preserved on failure. Indeed, one can see it would be highly likely to get overwritten.

Comment: This code also uses system_category instead of generic_category which is wrong.

Answer (score -3):

check this code:

uSTL is a partial implementation of the C++ standard library that focuses on
decreasing the memory footprint of user executables.

https://github.com/msharov/ustl/blob/master/fstream.cc

Comment: And why should we check that code in the context of this question?

Comment: Then you should show why/how in the argument. This is a link only answer that shows little or no effort at all. (I've looked at the code and it certainly doesn't help handle error conditions correctly and or portably). [A word](https://github.com/msharov/ustl/issues/25) from its project leader: ***"Windows is not and will not be supported. We should all do our part to discourage the existence of Windows."***

Comment: windows support problem is irrelevant, i only point fstream implementation.

Comment: Wow. So, you didn't read the question. In fact, not even the very first word. Of the title.